# json_encode not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this piece of code

```
<?php
include_once("../modelos/conexion.php");

$database = new Database();

$conexion = $database->getConnection();


$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT nombre_asignatura FROM asignaturas");
$statement->execute();
$asignaturas=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($asignaturas);

echo "<br><br><br>";

foreach ($asignaturas as $key => $value) {
    echo json_encode($value);
}
echo "<br><br><br>";
foreach ($asignaturas as $key => $value) {
    print_r($value);
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Which gives the following results

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yeYk.png)

[image]

I cannot understand why does it work only once. Also, is there a way to use ir to encode the whole array at once? I tried to use the "depth" variable, but I don't quite get it

Comment: Is it the non-English characters that are different in the input between the JSON output? I suspect it's not to do with "once", but rather related to the input - and this hypothesis can be tested.

Comment: `<?php
include_once("../modelos/conexion.php");

$database = new Database();

$conexion = $database->getConnection();


$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT nombre_asignatura FROM asignaturas");
$statement->execute();
$asignaturas=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($asignaturas);

echo "<br><br><br>";

$final_array_to_encode = array();
foreach ($asignaturas as $key => $value) {
   $final_array_to_encode[] = $value;
}
echo "<br><br><br>";
echo json_encode($final_array_to_encode);

?>`

Comment: A bit more info would help. What is the goal here?

Comment: The question code is illustrating that only one of the (nested) array/objects is echo'ed (the one with "English TIM" as the only item) when JSON encoding them separately in a loop.

Comment: what are you doing? just use `echo json_encode($asignaturas);` to encode the whole array, don't feed it inside the `foreach` thats completely unnecessary

Comment: I echoed the items one at a time for debbuging, as the first thing I tried was to encode the whole array at once. But it displayed nothing at all, so I started to look for the place where it breaks and why. One of the answers found out that the problem is the utf-8 codification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_last_error()` will help figuring out what is wrong: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

As @user2864... pointed out I also guess it is the special characters that fail. Also as @Ghost pointed out, don't foreach encode.

json_encode($array)

In case this will fail debug with the json_last_error().

Comment: @Brad: you misunderstood my point. Since just the first one gets into the array the asking person should debug, I see nothing wrong within the code. And debugging is the way to go. I wrote that somebody answered with that hint and that is my guess, not that it is.  You are too fast with the downvote trigger rather give an answer if you know better.

Comment: Ghost already posted an appropriate answer... no need for a duplicate.

Comment: "I see nothing wrong within the code" -- yet you correctly say, *do not `foreach` encode*. *That* is something wrong. I suspect that when the OP says, 'it only works once', he actually means "it only works if I have just one record".

Comment: You were right, it was a codification error. I did the foreach loop to try and debug, but did not know how to. The foreach loop gives a "5" error with all the ones it does not display, as well as with trying to encode the whole array at once. By the way, the purpose of this is to take the names of the subjects of a course and send them to angular (which I'm also trying to learn).

Comment: Finally I had to encode the whole array to utf-8 (I thought it already was utf-8, as the var_dump showed accents) and then echo it with the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE option. I thing i'm good to go now. Thank you all!